# Icon right on navbar don't work on ios as expected

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

Example on `android/Browser`

[Works Fine on Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyzue.png)

Example On `Ios`

[Not work as well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnhVe.png)

> page.html

```
<ion-header [scrollHide]="headerScrollConfig" [scrollContent]="pageContent" >
    <ion-navbar color="ticket-blue-rainbow" >
        <ion-row>
            <ion-title> {{ evento.descricao }}</ion-title>
            <ion-icon class="padding-icon" name="thumbs-up" color="light" item-right icon-right (click)="likeEvento()"></ion-icon>
            <ion-icon class="padding-icon" name="ios-heart" item-right color="danger" (click)="onClickFavorit()"></ion-icon>
            <ion-icon class="padding-icon" name="share" item-right (click)="onClickOpenModal()" color="light" style="padding-right: 10px !important;"></ion-icon>
        </ion-row>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

> page.scss

```
 .padding-icon {
    padding-right: 15px;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don’t no if this method is the most correctly, but in this situation i use this class on `ios`

```
.ios {
  page-event
 {
    .padding-ios{
      padding-left:70%!important;
    }
  }
}
```

and on `html` i used

```
<ion-buttons right class="padding-ios"> 
</ion-buttons>
```

Answer (score 0):

To overcome above issue you need to use below option with `<ion-buttons>` tag

```
<ion-buttons right>
   <ion-icon class="padding-icon" name="thumbs-up" color="light" item-right icon-right 
   (click)="likeEvento()"></ion-icon>
</ion-buttons>
```

It will work and show your buttons on right side.

Comment: Can you update your que with new screen output so I can have some idea whats going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>

    <ion-title> {{ evento.descricao }}</ion-title>

    <ion-buttons right>
        <ion-icon class="padding-icon" name="thumbs-up" color="light" item-right icon-right (click)="likeEvento()"></ion-icon>
        <ion-icon class="padding-icon" name="ios-heart" item-right color="danger" (click)="onClickFavorit()"></ion-icon>
        <ion-icon class="padding-icon" name="share" item-right (click)="onClickOpenModal()" color="light" style="padding-right: 10px !important;"></ion-icon>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>
```